# How to use two loss functions for a single model in keras?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I want to use one keras model for two different purposes. One using a CTC Loss Function and Another using Categorical Crossentropy loss function. 
This is my model in keras:

```python
def train(run_name, start_epoch, stop_epoch, img_w,type_t):

  input_data = Input(name='the_input', shape=input_shape, dtype='float32')
  inner = Conv2D(conv_filters, kernel_size, padding='same',
                 activation=act, kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                 name='conv1')(input_data)
  inner = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(pool_size, pool_size), name='max1')(inner)
  inner = Conv2D(conv_filters, kernel_size, padding='same',
                 activation=act, kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                 name='conv2')(inner)
  inner = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(pool_size, pool_size), name='max2')(inner)
  inner_act = Flatten()(inner_act)

  inner_2 = Dense(1,
                    name='dense3')(inner_act)
  inner_out = Activation('sigmoid')(inner_2)
  conv_to_rnn_dims = (img_w // (pool_size ** 2), (img_h // (pool_size ** 2)) * conv_filters)
  inner = Reshape(target_shape=conv_to_rnn_dims, name='reshape')(inner)


  inner = Dense(time_dense_size, activation=act, name='dense1')(inner)

  gru_1 = GRU(rnn_size, return_sequences=True, kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='gru1')(inner)
  gru_1b = GRU(rnn_size, return_sequences=True, go_backwards=True, kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='gru1_b')(inner)
  gru1_merged = add([gru_1, gru_1b])
  gru_2 = GRU(rnn_size, return_sequences=True, kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='gru2')(gru1_merged)
  gru_2b = GRU(rnn_size, return_sequences=True, go_backwards=True, kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='gru2_b')(gru1_merged)

  inner = Dense(FindOutPutShape(), kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                name='dense2')(concatenate([gru_2, gru_2b]))
  y_pred = Activation('softmax', name='softmax')(inner)
  Model(inputs=input_data, outputs=y_pred)

  labels = Input(name='the_labels', shape=[img_gen.absolute_max_string_len], dtype='float32')
  input_length = Input(name='input_length', shape=[1], dtype='int64')
  label_length = Input(name='label_length', shape=[1], dtype='int64')


  loss_out = Lambda(ctc_lambda_func, output_shape=(1,), name='ctc')([y_pred, labels, input_length, label_length])

  # clipnorm seems to speeds up convergence
  sgd = SGD(lr=0.02, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True, clipnorm=5)

  model_1 = Model(inputs=[input_data, labels, input_length, label_length], outputs=loss_out)
  model_2 = Model(inputs=input_data, outputs=inner_out)
```

I want to perform a minmax game where in the begining I am going to train model_1 and than I am going to train the same model of model_1 but few of the layers would been chopped off which is the model_2. Are the weights going to be same or not. If not then is it possible to perform this task?

Comment: What do you mean by your model having the same weights? If you mean that at the beginning of training your second model will have the same weights as at the end of training first model - the answer is yes.